# Edit a single Xcode project in multiple computers

Tags: xcode, git

I've been working on a Xcode project in my iMac but now that I have a MacBook Air I would like to continue working on that project when maybe I am traveling or in a place where I don't have my iMac. My question is that if there is any way to edit a single Xcode project in multiple computers, I heard something about Git but I don't know exactly what it does. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do this using Git, but your question is too broad to receive an answer.  Read the Git setup tutorial and come back if you still have a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is version control software. If you're just getting started on programming, I'd highly recommend learning how to use it--it will make your programming life dramatically easier.

Essentially, it allows you to save different versions of your software that can be accessed from different computers. You can create branches for different features of your software.

Let's say you've got an existing `master` and you want to add a new ViewController. Rather than risk messing up your entire project, you can create a branch, add your ViewController, and once it's working properly, you can commit it to the repository and merge it with your `master`.

Here's a video tutorial on it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fKg7e37bQE

Here's a cheatsheet that should be helpful getting started:

https://training.github.com/kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf

You'll want to enable git repositories on your Xcode projects. You can also use Git within Xcode, but I was taught to use it via Terminal and I find it easier in Terminal.

There's a website called GitHub where you can save your repositories and access others' repositories. You can also search for code in the repositories that are publicly posted there. As the other user stated, this is a very broad topic, but I'd highly encourage you to learn it. I wish that had been my first step when I started to learn iOS.